# angular2 and routing - adding a query parm to child

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

Wow

```
this.router.navigate(['/services', {outlets: {'servicelistright': ['servicelist']}}]);
```

If I the below to the url I get get the query parm using the below:

```
         http://localhost:4200/#/services/(servicelistright:servicelist;type=11)

this.route.params.map(params => params['type'])
            .subscribe(type => { console.log('stupid',type) });
```

Well I think is just wonderful..wow great...

But how on earth do I add the query parm?

1) by using router.navigate

```
this.router.navigate(['/services', {outlets: {'servicelistright': ['servicelist']}}]);
```

where do I add type=11???

Or my routerLink

```
<a md-raised-button  routerLinkActive="['active']" [routerLink]="['/services']" ">Raised button</a>
```

Comment: hey, did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42600394/2545680) help?

Comment: so no comment regarding [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42600394/2545680)?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed to the route in a form of an object. For example, to get this query string:

```
/inbox/33;details=true/messages/44;mode=preview
```

you need to use the following array:

```
['/inbox', 33, {details: true}, 'messages', 44, {mode: 'preview'}]
```

So in your case you can pass the `type` param like that to `router.navigate`:

```
this.router.navigate(['/services', {outlets: {'servicelistright': ['servicelist', {type: 11}]}}]);
```

behind the scenes, `routerLink` just calls `router.navigate`, so you can pass the same `URL` string to the directive:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/services', {outlets: {'servicelistright': ['servicelist', {type: 11}]}}]">Go</a>
```