# RouterLink- angular2, child route and a query string

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

angular2,

How do I add a query query to a nested route in this format?

This works in ts file:

```
routerLink = ['/output', {outlets: {'output': ['details']}}] 

http://localhost:4200/#/output/(output:details)
```

How do I modify to add a query parm?
URL should like like this:

```
    http://localhost:4200/#/output/(output:details;id=1)
```

Comment: Dude that did a hit and run....do explain...

Comment: hey, I also answered a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600241/angular2-and-routing-adding-a-query-parm-to-child/42600394#42600394) to your question, did it help?

Comment: Yup!  Like a charm..thanks

Comment: great, you can upvote or accept it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters as objects to URL segments like this:

```
router.navigate([
     '/inbox', 33, {details: true}, 'messages', 44, {mode: 'preview'}
])
```

So in your case it will like this:

```
routerLink = ['/output', {outlets: {'output': ['details', {id: 1}]}}] 
                                                           ^^^^^
```

this will generate the URL:

```
/output/(output:details;id=1)
```